# Crop plot 1 according to the shape of plot 2

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, crop

I'm trying to plot a heatmap with the plt.pcolormesh, and then plot the outline of my figure with the plt.scatter and I would like to crop the result according to the shape of the last plot which is the outline.

It doesn't seem that hard to do but still I haven't managed to do it or found anything. Here is my code and an image to illustrate, thank you for your help!

```
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (10.0, 10.0) 
plt.axis("off")
plt.pcolormesh(x, y, intens)
plt.colorbar()
coord = np.genfromtxt("myfile.csv", delimiter = ' ')
x = [coord[i][0] for i in range(0, len(coord))]
y = [coord[i][1] for i in range(0, len(coord))]
plt.scatter(x, y, c = 'k', s = 1.)
```

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQ1IY.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can just use plt.xlim() and plt.ylim() and give them the coordinates of the new figure. Here is a modified version of the code:

```
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (10.0, 10.0)
plt.axis('off')
plt.pcolormesh(x, y, intens)
plt.colorbar()
coord = np.genfromtxt('myfile.csv', delimiter=' ')
x = coord[:, 0]
y = coord[:, 1]

plt.scatter(x, y, c='k', s=1.)

plt.xlim([np.min(x), np.max(x)])
plt.ylim([np.min(y), np.max(y)])
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, especially for the shorter version to take the x and y coordinates, as you can see I'm a beginner on python :p

I'm actually having the same result, it's scaling to the size of the 2nd figure, but I'd like to crop it so that it's just following the outline.
So here I would like to delete everything outside the white figure : [Here is the example](https://s31.postimg.org/b68jqe3gr/test2.png)